# How do I group points into several circles with a given radius?

Tags: geometry

There is a set of points on the Cartesian coordinate system. How do I group points into several circles with a given radius and meeting the following requirements:

- each point belongs to a group **at least**， specifically,

  - circles can intersect
  - a point can belong to several circles
  - points can be placed on the boundray
- the number of groups is minimum

For instance, group the following points into 3 circles.

[image]

Comment: A point can't belong to two circles? Circles can or can't intersect? [Thanks for edit]

Comment: @AlexClark A point can belong to several circles. Overlapping is allowed.

Comment: Is $(0,1)$ in the circle $\{(x,y): \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq 1, x,y\in \Bbb R\}$ Or does it need to not lie on the boundary?

Comment: @AlexClark, it is OK to lie on the boundary, i.e., $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq r$

Comment: Btw what sort of answer is wanted? Do you want a computational sort of answer, or do you want a way to find the number of circles(or both, or other)?

Comment: @AlexClark, minimize the number of base stations (or say WiFi access points) that should be built and therefore all points can be covered by wireless networks. Here, the radius $r$ represents the **transimission range**.

Comment: This paper may have things to say about your problem. http://compgeom.com/~piyush/papers/kcenter.pdf

Comment: @MatthewConroy, thx,  *k-center* is to find a set of $k$ vertices for which the **largest** distance of any point to its closest vertex in the *k-set* is minimum.

Comment: This lookes similar to [a question I once asked on the Statistics SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/66006/15959).